# wx.lib.sheet column and row names

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to somehow change column and row names in wx.lib.sheet widget?
From A, B, C, D to Name, Surname, Age, DOB for example.

If not is there any similar way to make Sheetlike data input GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as `wx.lib.sheet.CSheet` class extends `wx.grid.Grid`, there's `SetColLabelValue` method:

```
column_names = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Age', 'DOB']
sheet = CSheet(panel)
for index, name in enumerate(column_names):
    sheet.SetColLabelValue(index, name)
sizer.Add(sheet)
```

`SetRowLabelValue` is for rows.